# Data Manipulation - shifting rows manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, shift

I have a Pandas DataFrame and I want to loop through the `column 1` and if the column value is `vergleich` I shift the row cells once to the right.

Here is my attempt:

```
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    if j[1]== "stringobject":
        df.shift(periods=1,axis=1)
print(df)
```

When I print df, I do not see any changes. Kindly advise how to go about this

Comment: Please, please, **do not post images**! If you had given your sample data as text, we could copy it and try to reproduce. I will never type all that data...

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try this using this MCVE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,'A','A'],'col2':['A','A','A','Z','Z'], 'col3':['Z','Z','Z', np.nan, np.nan]})

#col1 col2 col3
#0    1    A    Z
#1    2    A    Z
#2    3    A    Z
#3    A    Z  NaN
#4    A    Z  NaN 

m = df['col1'] == 'A'
df[m] = df[m].shift(1, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    1    A    Z
1    2    A    Z
2    3    A    Z
3  NaN    A    Z
4  NaN    A    Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cut this chunk off, add the first column, and concat them back

```
verg = df.groupby(1).apply(lambda g: g if g.name != 'vergleigh' else g.T.shift(1).T)
```

Edit:
It's kind of weird, but `g.T.shift(1).T` works while `g.shift(1, axis=1)` does not. Why?